# RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'> on python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, spyder, python-telegram-bot

I want to develop a bot in telegram using spyder:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater
bot = telegram.Bot(token='***')
```

I get the above error.

Comment: Not so elegant fix: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5299

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Spyder 3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue with Spyder 3.2.6,

All you have to do is open Spyder with admin privileges, and the problem goes away. It's a temporary fix, but 100 percent works.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a known [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5299) and it was fixed in our **3.2.8** version, released on March/2018.

Comment: @danieltalsky, please update your Spyder version. This bug was fixed already (I updated the answer accordingly).